# Deleting an element in json array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to delete the element from json array using nodejs. My json file `match.json` is as follows.

```
[{"id":"1234","time":"3"}]
```

from this I want to delete the first element so that the json file looks like this:

```
[]
```

I tried the following code,its printing an empty array in the console but it is not removing the elements from the `match.json` file

```
for(var i=0;i<w;i++)
{
    for(var j=0;j<m;j++){
        if((words[i].id==match[j].id) && (words[i].time==match[j].time))
        {
            var f1=0;
            //var id1=match[j].id;
            var linkadd=words[i].link;   
            delete match[j];
            console.log(match);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you did not recognize the true purpose of JSON: don't work with the string representation directly. You can simply create an object out of your JSON file by *parsing* it, then you can transform your object and *serialize* it back to JSON. Much easier and much less error-prone.

Comment: do you always want to remove first element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **match.splice(i, 1)** instead of **delete match[i]**

Comment: i tried it ,it is printing empty on console but in the file the data is remaining.

Comment: are you rewriting your file after that operation with match array?

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = JSON.parse(Match_json_data);

// remove 1st element
var indexOfItemToRemove = 0;
var noOfItemsToRemove = 1;
arr.splice(indexOfItemToRemove, noOfItemsToRemove);
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice?v=control

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
let myJsonString = '[{"id":"1234","time":"3"}]';
let myEditedJsonString = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(myJsonString).shift());
```

Answer (score 0):

to remove the element..you can use splice.. The element will be removed.

```
    {
        var f1=0;
        //var id1=match[j].id;
        var linkadd=words[i].link;   
        match.splice(i, 1);
        console.log(match);
    }
```

If you use `delete match[i]`, the list becomes `[undefined]`. So use splice.

So basically delete does not delete the element, rather it sets the element as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const items = [{"id":"1234","time":"3"}]

console.log('before removing item ==> ', items)

items.splice(0 /*index to be removed*/, 1/*no. of items to be removed*/)

console.log('after removing item ==> ', items)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to always take out the first element and update the array the use the following code.

`var arr =[{"id":"1234","time":"3"}]`

`arr.reverse().pop()`

If you want to get a subset of the array you can slice the array but it will not update the array but create a new array.

`arr.slice(STARTING_ADDRESS,NO_OF_ELEMENTS_TO_SLICE)`

**NOTE**: This will return a new array, So if you want to update the old array then you need to assign it to the old array.

`arr = arr.slice(STARTING_ADDRESS,NO_OF_ELEMENTS_TO_SLICE)`